# Linked list data retrieve/ display issue

Tags: c, linux, list, kernel-module, arp

I have a requirement to obtain `arp` data of the current device. I followed an online example - http://rikiji.it/2011/04/17/Linux-kernel-programming-exercises-1.html to perform this task. This example addresses a solution to identify arp spoofing.

But I used its necessary functions to obtain the arp details stored such as the `ip` and the `mac` address. My issue is, the function obtains the data, but, when i add these information to a `list` and print the data while traversing, i get bogus data displayed. not the ones that I stored.

I don't know what is going on and I tried everything I can to solve but no luck.

following is the `struct` used,

```
struct neigh_list_t {
    unsigned char   ha[ALIGN(MAX_ADDR_LEN, sizeof(unsigned long))];
    u8 primary_key[0];
    struct list_head list;
} neigh_list;
```

The following are the methods that implements the `initialization`, `storing`, and `displaying` data.

```
static struct workqueue_struct * workq;
static DECLARE_DELAYED_WORK(work, arp_tbl_check);

void neigh_print(struct neigh_list_t * n, void * null)
{
    char tbuf[16], hbuffer[HBUFFERLEN];

    sprintf(tbuf, "%pI4", n->primary_key);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "%-16s\n",tbuf);
}

void neigh_handler(struct neighbour * n, void * null)
{
    struct neigh_list_t *tmp;

    int found = 0;
    char hbuffer[HBUFFERLEN];


    /* search */
    list_for_each_entry(tmp, &neigh_list.list, list) {      
        neigh_print(tmp, NULL);
        if(memcmp(n->ha,tmp->ha,n->dev->addr_len)==0) {
              format_hwaddr(n->ha, n->dev->addr_len, hbuffer);
              printk(KERN_ALERT "duplicated entry: %s\n", hbuffer);
              found = 1;
            }

    }   


    /* add an entry */
    if(!found) {
        struct neigh_list_t * new_entry = (struct neigh_list_t *) kmalloc(sizeof(struct neigh_list_t), GFP_KERNEL);
        memcpy(new_entry->ha,n->ha,n->dev->addr_len);
        memcpy(new_entry->primary_key,n->primary_key,sizeof(u8 *));
        list_add(&(new_entry->list), &(neigh_list.list));
    }
}

void arp_tbl_check(struct work_struct * w)
{


    struct list_head *pos, *q;
    struct neigh_list_t * tmp;

    neigh_for_each(&arp_tbl, neigh_handler, NULL);

    /* empty list */
    list_for_each_safe(pos, q, &neigh_list.list){
            tmp= list_entry(pos, struct neigh_list_t, list);
            list_del(pos);
            kfree(tmp);
    }
    queue_delayed_work(workq, &work, HZ * 5);

}

static int arp_init(void)
{

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&neigh_list.list);   
    printk(KERN_ALERT "arpcheck init\n");

    workq = create_singlethread_workqueue("arp_tbl_check_wq");
    queue_delayed_work(workq, &work, HZ * 5);
    return 0;
}
```

**P.S**

For the IP addresses `192.168.1.1` and `127.0.0.1` the function prints `0.195.27.160` and `224.39.125.54`.

My guess is there is an issue when storing (`memcpy`) or when trying to display data. I have no idea how to fix this.

**EDIT**-test-printing the content of the linked list,

```
  char tbuf[16];//newly added to print IP

  /* search */
  list_for_each_entry(tmp, &neigh_list.list, list) {

        sprintf(tbuf, "%pI4", tmp->primary_key);//newly added to print IP
        printk(KERN_ALERT "-----IP - %-16s\n",tbuf);//newly added to print IP

        if(memcmp(n->ha,tmp->ha,n->dev->addr_len)==0) {
            format_hwaddr(n->ha, n->dev->addr_len, hbuffer);
            printk(KERN_ALERT "duplicated entry: %s\n", hbuffer);
            found = 1;
        }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by primary_key[0] in structure?. Is it right?. You are trying to print content of list in structure i.e  printing memory address as ip address

Comment: Here is the full code. https://github.com/rikiji/arpcheck/blob/master/arpcheck.c

Comment: @Sasi thank you for replying sir, `primary_key[0]` is where I store the IP address. do you know how it can be corrected? the `neighbour.h` header suggestes to use `u8 primary_key[0]` for IP. yes and I am aware of the full code, however, that is the code that provides different outputs. :)

Comment: It prints correctly for me
[12911.684150] 192.168.100.10    tun0
[12911.684163] 255.255.255.255  ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff wlo1
[12911.684168] 192.168.1.2      00:00:00:00:00:00 lo
[12911.684172] 239.255.255.250  01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa wlo1
[12911.684178] 224.0.0.22       01:00:5e:00:00:16 wlo1
[12911.684182] 192.168.1.1      4c:60:de:42:81:55 wlo1
[12911.684190] 224.0.0.251      01:00:5e:00:00:fb wlo1

Comment: @Sasi oh.. did you try printing out data stored in the `linkedlist` within the loop `list_for_each_entry(tmp, &neigh_list.list, list)` in the function `neigh_handler` ? because that is where I got erroneous outputs. ALso did you make any changes to the `neigh_print` function?

Comment: @Sasi try printing the linked list data using the following command I have posted as an edit in my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify neigh_list_t structure fields as mentioned below

```
struct neigh_list_t {
  struct list_head list;
  unsigned char ha[ALIGN(MAX_ADDR_LEN, sizeof(unsigned long))];
  u8 primary_key[0];
} neigh_list;
```

O/p With your printk 
   ================

```
[ 1456.124639] 192.168.1.1      4c:60:de:42:81:55 wlo1
[ 1456.124652] -----IP - 192.168.1.1     
[ 1456.124658] 127.0.0.1        00:00:00:00:00:00 lo
[ 1456.124661] -----IP - 127.0.0.1       
[ 1456.124665] -----IP - 192.168.1.1     
[ 1456.124669] 224.0.0.251      01:00:5e:00:00:fb wlo1
[ 1456.124673] -----IP - 224.0.0.251     
[ 1456.124677] -----IP - 127.0.0.1       
[ 1456.124680] -----IP - 192.168.1.1     
[ 1456.124684] 224.0.0.22       01:00:5e:00:00:16 wlo1
```

Comment: Just a small question off topic. will `memcmp` work if i try to umpare an IP stored in an `unsigned int` variable and this `u8` variable? like - `unsigned int src_ip; memcpy(tmp->primary_key, src_ip);`

Comment: ohhh i hv a made a mistake i meant `unsigned int src_ip; memcmp(tmp->primary_key, src_ip);`

Comment: It depends on how you store the Ip address in src_ip and primary_key and how many bytes you are going to compare?. memcpy(new_entry->primary_key,n->primary_key,sizeof(u8 *));" this is how you are copying the data.